# Redirect logs to syslog server using SNMP

Tags: logging, server, snmp, syslog, syslog-ng

Hi im currently working on a syslog server using syslog-ng and storing the data in Mysql table.
My boss asked me to receive logs transmitted via SNMP protocol, is there any code to add to syslog-ng.conf file to achieve that ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

newer versions of [syslog-ng can receive SNMP traps](https://syslog-ng.com/documents/html/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/syslog-ng-source-snmptrap.html).